# How can I use the npm packages from feed in my VSTS task?

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

How can I use the npm packages from feed in my VSTS task? As I want to use the cached packages in my build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the packages are in your VSTS feed, the simple way is choose corresponding feed in npm task:

1. Add npm task (Command: `install`; Working folder with package.json: `[package.json folder path]`)
2. Choose **Registry I select here**
3. Choose your feed

[image]

Otherwise, just add npm task (Command: install; Working folder with package.json: [package.json folder path]

Comment: There is no registry choose option in VSTS npm task. Can you share the screenshot?

Comment: @Twinkle Do you use 0.* version of npm task? Change it to 1.* version and expend Custom registries and authentication section.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check this. :) :)

Comment: @Twinkle What's the result now? I added the screenshot to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It worked. Actually, I want to reduce my build runtime. Without this npm install task takes 3 mins to run And with this, it is taking more than 4 mins to run. So, Now It is not useful for me. But Thanks again. If you have some idea of reducing the build runtime you can share . :) :)

Comment: @Twinkle With private agent, you can retrieve the packages from cache.